# Latency in Snowflake Account Usage Views

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to understand "latency" issue with Account Usage Views.

Does the latency, let's say for Query History mentioned to be 45 min, mean it might take 45 min for a query to pull result out of Account Usage view or does it mean it might take time for data to be available in Account Usage view?

When I query Account Usage in a trial account, query doesnt take much time on Account Usage view and also Account Usage view shows latest sql details in Query History so I am not able to understand what latency denote.

Another question is if latency means the amount of time SQL will take to pull result I assume it will keep the Warehouse in running state increasing the cost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Data latency](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#data-latency)

> Due to the process of extracting the data from Snowflake’s internal metadata store, the account usage views have some natural latency:
>
> - For most of the views, the latency is 2 hours (120 minutes).
> - For the remaining views, the latency varies between 45 minutes and 3 hours.
>
> For details, see the list of views for each schema (in this topic). Also, note that these are all maximum time lengths; the actual latency for a given view when the view is queried may be less.

---

> "Does the latency, let's say for Query History mentioned to be 45 min, mean it might take 45 min for a query to pull result out of Account Usage view or does it mean it might take time for data to be available in Account Usage view?"

The terms latency refers to the time until  the data will be available in Account Usage view.

It does not mean that query `SELECT * FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.<some_view>`  takes 45 minutes to execute.